# How to sum all properties of a nested collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given I got User.attachments and Attachment.visits as an integer with the number count.

How can I easily count all the visits of all images of that user?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [ActiveRecord::Base#sum](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/sum):

```
user.attachments.sum(:visits)
```

This should generate an efficient SQL query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(attachments.visits) FROM attachments WHERE attachments.user_id = ID
```

Comment: What if you wanted to sum a scope of visits.  For instance, visits has scope :active, -> { where('attribute IS NOT NULL') }.  Something like "user.attachments.sum(visits.active) ?

Answer (score 17):

```
user.attachments.map{|a| a.visits}.sum
```

Comment: or `user.attachments.map(&:visits).sum`

Comment: or `user.attachments.sum(&:visits)`

Comment: Indeed, @Jordon's solution is the best.

Comment: When :visits is a column in the attachments table, yes, user.attachments.sum(:visits) is best.  If it's strictly a method on the object, however, then some variant of Calin, rubyprince, or Jordan's solution (Enumerable sum) is required.

Answer (score 5):

There's also `inject`:

```
user.attachments.inject(0) { |sum, a| sum + a.visits }
```

People generally (and quite rightly) hate `inject`, but since the two other main ways of achieving this have been mentioned, I thought I may as well throw it out there. :)

Answer (score 2):

The following works with Plain Old Ruby Objects, and I suspect the following is marginally faster than using `count += a.visits`, plus it has an emoticon in it:

```
user.attachments.map(&:visits).inject(:+)
```

Comment: Hahahahah by far, best answer hahaha